# How to write the output of this statement into a file in Golang

Tags: file, go, io

I'm trying to write the output of the statement below into a text file but I can't seem to find out if there is a printf function that writes directly to a text file. For example if the code below produces the results [5 1 2 4 0 3] I would want to read this into a text file for storage and persistence. Any ideas please?

The code I want to goto the text file:

```
//choose random number for recipe
r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
i := r.Perm(5)
fmt.Printf("%v\n", i)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", i[0])
fmt.Printf("%d\n", i[1])
```

Comment: Users who are watching this questing may  be interested in **How to write log to file in Go** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965795/how-to-write-log-to-file

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`fmt.Fprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) together with an `io.Writer`, which would represent a handle to your file.

Here is a simple example:

```
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("/tmp/yourfile")
    check(err)
    defer f.Close()

    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    //choose random number for recipe
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    i := r.Perm(5)

    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i)
    check(err)
    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d\n", i[0])
    check(err)
    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d\n", i[1])
    check(err)
    w.Flush()
}
```

More ways of writing to file in Go are shown [here](https://gobyexample.com/writing-files).

Note that I have used `panic()` here just for the sake of brevity, in the real life scenario you should handle errors appropriately (which in most cases means something other than exiting the program, what `panic()` does).

Comment: Interesting, would there be an example i could follow?

Comment: I may nitpick here, but I think it would be nice to mention for those who are not familiar with Go that panicking in those circumstances may not be appropriate in a real case scenario.

Comment: @basgys Sure, I have added it.

Answer (score 5):

This example will write the values into the `output.txt` file.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.OpenFile("output.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("File does not exists or cannot be created")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    i := r.Perm(5)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i)

    w.Flush()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `os` package to create file and then pass it to `Fprintf`

```
file, fileErr := os.Create("file")
if fileErr != nil {
    fmt.Println(fileErr)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(file, "%v\n", i)
```

This should write to file.